# property of integral of complex valued function of real variable

Tags: complex-analysis

i have a question about this.

if $f(t):[a,b] \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function, then is there a property in complex analysis that states,

$ | \int_a^b f(t) dt | \leq \int_a^b |f(t)| dt $ ??

I know there is one for real valued function, if yes, then is there a simple proof for it that use this property for real function to extend it to the complex case??

thank you.

Comment: Yes. It is true. Take $f=f_1+if_2$ and apply real case to $f_j$

Comment: @sinbadh  do you mean it like this??  $$ | \int_a^b f(t) dt| = | \int_a^b f_1(t) dt + i \int_a^b f_2(t) dt | \leq | \int_a^b f_1(t) dt | + | \int_a^b f_2(t) dt| \leq \int_a^b ( |f_1(t)| + |f_2(t)| ) dt $$ .  \\ But $ |f(t)| \leq |f_1(t)| + |f_2(t)|$ though???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = re^{i\theta}$. Then 
$$\left|\int_a^b f(t) \, dt\right| = \operatorname{Re} \left(e^{-i\theta}\int_a^b f(t) \, dt \right) = \int_a^b \operatorname{Re}\left(e^{-i\theta}f(t)\right)\, dt \leq \int_a^b |f(t)| \, dt.$$

Comment: Thank you for helping me again.  This is a really neat proof. But Is there a proof that extend the absolute property of the real case integral to the complex case?

Comment: That is what David has just done here!

Comment: The inequality that is used here for integrals of real functions is that if $f \leq g$, then $\int f \leq \int g$. I don't know a proof that uses $|\int f| \leq \int |f|$ for real functions.